# How to get Data after change by using Document based App

Tags: objective-c

I am using NSFileWrapper to get data when user click Save button.

I override -fileWrapperOfType:error: as below

```
 
- (NSFileWrapper*) fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)outError {

    NSFileWrapper *removedFile = [self.documentFileWrapper.fileWrappers objectForKey:@"test.rtf"];
    [self.documentFileWrapper removeFileWrapper:removedFile];

    NSFileWrapper *newFile = [[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:[@"File was changed" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    newFile.preferredFilename = self.documentFileWrapper.filename;

    [self.documentFileWrapper addFileWrapper:newFile];

    return self.documentFileWrapper;
}
```

When I run, I got below error

-[NSFileWrapper fileWrappers] *** this method is only for directory type NSFileWrappers

Please find my project at below:

 [Demo_NSFileWrapper](https://github.com/nexttrang/Demo_NSFileWrapper/blob/1d956e85bf7df232edefb8c0abe79ad05054dac6/Demo_NSFileWrapper.zip)

Comment: What you tried? You code?

Comment: @timiTao: I updated my code, please check it again

Comment: The Xcode template of `Document` says "Insert code here to write your document to data of the specified type.". You have to put your data in a `NSData` object and return it, as you do, but instead of `fhcfytryctcytcycyt` you should use real data ofcourse. Which data do you want to save?

Comment: @Willeke: the problem is that I cannot get the current data. and that is the reason I put a string @"fhcfytryctcytcycyt" temporarily.  Could you provide me the solution to get data in a NSData? I referring NSFileWrapper for this issue. Could I use it to save file?

Comment: How do you put the data in the text field?

Comment: @Willeke: I have updated my question and project. Could you help me check it again? Thank you very much

Comment: When you do `self.documentFileWrapper = fileWrapper`, `fileWrapper` isn't a directory filewrapper.

Comment: @Willeke: Thank you very much. Now, I got it